# C++: How do I assign a char variable to a vector<char> and access elements of that vector for comparison?

Tags: c++, vector, char

I'm trying to write a Hangman program, and I'm having issues with a vector.

I can't compare elements of it to an inputted char, nor assign elements to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
int letterFill(char userGuess, vector<char> wordAnswer, vector<char>*Guess) {
    int n = wordAnswer.size();
    int a;
    int match = 0;

    for (a=0; a<n; a++) {


        if (userGuess == wordAnswer[a]) {
            Guess[a] = userGuess; //Error
            match ++;
        }

        else if (Guess[a] == userGuess)//Error {
            cout<< "You've already guessed that letter!\n";
        }

        else {
            numMistake = numMistake + 1;
            drawHangman();
        }

    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: and the error you get is?

Comment: why `vector<char> *Guess` instead of `vector<char> Guess`

Comment: perhaps you want `vector<char>& Guess` instead?

Comment: What's the difference between &Guess, *Guess and Guess?

Comment: `&Guess` = reference to vector `Guess` |                                            `*Guess` = pointer to vector `Guess`  |                                                     `Guess` = vector `Guess` itself

Answer (score 0):

Problem might reside on the fact that `Guess` is a pointer to vector, rather than the vector itself. I would rather pass it by reference. But there should not be any difference.
Try accessing the element like `(*Guess).at(a)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the vectors by reference instead of plain old c pointers and values.
Also using algorithms and the standard library guarantees you expressive, easy to read and maintai code and free of easy mistakes that you are prone to while crafting your own code.. I hope the snippet will help you understand the basic concept.

```
int letterFill(const char user_guess, std::vector<char>& word_answer, std::vector<char>& guess){
    int num_mistake = 0;
    int match = 0;

    auto res = find(word_answer.begin(), word_answer.end(), user_guess);
    if(res != word_answer.end()) /*Correct answer*/{
         guess.push_back(word_answer);
         match ++;
    }else{/*not found, so look for it in guess*/
        auto gsd = find(guess.begin(), guess.end(), user_guess);
        if(gsd != guess.end()) cerr << "You've already guessed that letter \n";
        else{
            num_mistake ++; //increment the mistakes made .. i guess
            draw_hangman();
       }
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess[a] is a `std::vector<char>` not a char, because Guess is a pointer to a vector. So when you try to assign it a char like so:

```
Guess[a] = userGuess
```

You predictably get a compiler error. Something like

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<char>’ and ‘char’)
```

Which is saying you cannot assign a char to a vector.

As others have suggested, the easiest thing to do is simply not use a pointer to a vector.